# Multiple Http.Get hanging randomly

Tags: go

I am trying to learn Golang and took on a simple project to call all the craigslist cities and query them for a specific search. In the code below I removed all the links in the listingmap but there are over 400 links there. So the loop is fairly large. I thought this would be a good test to put what I am learning into application but I am running into a strange issue.

Some of the times most of the Http.Get() get no response from the server while others it gets them all with no problem. So I started adding prints to show how many error out and we recovered and how many successfully made it through. Also while this is running it will randomly hang and never respond. The program doesn't freeze but the site just sits there trying to load and the terminal shows no activity.

I am making sure my Response body is closed by deferring the cleanup after the recover but it still seems to not work. Is there something that jumps out to anyone that maybe I am missing?

Thanks in advance guys!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/xml"
    "sync"
    )

var wg sync.WaitGroup

var locationMap = map[string]string {"https://auburn.craigslist.org/": "auburn "...}

var totalRecovers int = 0
var successfulReads int = 0

type Listings struct {
    Links []string `xml:"item>link"`
    Titles []string `xml:"item>title"`
    Descriptions []string `xml:"item>description"`
    Dates []string `xml:"item>date"`
}

type Listing struct {
    Title string
    Description string
    Date string
}

type ListAggPage struct {
        Title string
        Listings map[string]Listing
        SearchRequest string
}

func cleanUp(link string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    if r:= recover(); r!= nil {
        totalRecovers++
//      recoverMap <- link
    }
}

func cityRoutine(c chan Listings, link string) {
    defer cleanUp(link)

    var i Listings
    address := link + "search/sss?format=rss&query=motorhome"
    resp, rErr := http.Get(address)
    if(rErr != nil) {
        fmt.Println("Fatal error has occurs while getting response.")
        fmt.Println(rErr);
    }

    bytes, bErr := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if(bErr != nil) {
        fmt.Println("Fatal error has occurs while getting bytes.")
        fmt.Println(bErr);
    }
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &i)
    resp.Body.Close()
    c <- i
    successfulReads++
}

func listingAggHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    queue := make(chan Listings, 99999)
    listing_map := make(map[string]Listing)

    for key, _ := range locationMap {
        wg.Add(1)
        go cityRoutine(queue, key)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(queue)

    for elem := range queue { 
        for index, _ := range elem.Links {
        listing_map[elem.Links[index]] = Listing{elem.Titles[index * 2], elem.Descriptions[index], elem.Dates[index]}
        }
    }

    p := ListAggPage{Title: "Craigslist Aggregator", Listings: listing_map}
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("basictemplating.html")
    fmt.Println(t.Execute(w, p))

    fmt.Println("Successfully loaded: ", successfulReads)       
    fmt.Println("Recovered from: ", totalRecovers)
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Whoa, Go is neat!</h1>")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/agg/", listingAggHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil) 
}
```

Comment: I haven't read through the code really, but I think it's your package level `sync.WaitGroup`. You need to create one in the handler and pass it around.

Comment: Also, increments and decrements aren't thread safe, so `totalRecovers++` actually needs to be `atomic.AddInt64(&totalRecovers, 1)`, and the Printlines need to use `atomic.LoadInt64`.

Comment: Also, in `cityRoutine` you're not returning on error just printing to stdout, so execution will just continue. And you're not checking for the error returned from `xml.Unmarshal`.

Comment: Thnks for the information about the unsafe usages in my code. I am a little confused to why the waitgroup has to be passed versus being a public variable? I know it is better practice and I will be making a lot of changes if I plan to actually develop this into something intended for use. Right now it is purely educational so I wasn't too worried about global variables unless it can actually cause errors. As for allowing the code to continue, I thought it broke out after the error and then called the defer function. If it is finish the full function then maybe that is the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Every request spawns a new goroutine and those execute concurrently, so that `WaitGroup` is shared across threads, across every request.

Comment: Go code doesn't have exceptions, so errors don't automatically break out. Errors are not "special" in go, they are just values like anything else (say an int or a string) and the caller can do what they want with them. Generally you check the error and then return if one was returned. But that's not automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble finding the golang mailing list discussion I was reading in reference to this, but you generally don't want to open up hundreds of requests. There's some information here: [How Can I Effectively 'Max Out' Concurrent HTTP Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318419/how-can-i-effectively-max-out-concurrent-http-requests)

Craigslist might also just be rate limiting you. Either way, I recommend limiting to around 20 simultaneous requests or so, here's a quick update to your `listingAggHandler`.

```
queue := make(chan Listings, 99999)
listing_map := make(map[string]Listing)

request_queue := make(chan string)
for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
    go func() {
        for {
            key := <- request_queue
            cityRoutine(queue, key)                
        }
    }()
}

for key, _ := range locationMap {
    wg.Add(1)
    request_queue <- key
}

wg.Wait()
close(request_queue)
close(queue)
```

The application should still be very fast. I agree with the other comments on your question as well. Would also try and avoid putting so much in the global scope.

You could also spruce my changes up a little by just using the wait group in the request pool and have each goroutine clean itself up and decrement the wait group. That would limit some of the global scope.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say but I don't think the above code would actually work. You are making a request_queue channel and iterating 20 times. You are copying the empty channel into key and running the cityRoutine function on it as a regular call, not a go routine. Then later you are iterating over my map with keys and putting it in the request_queue but never using it now that it has the keys... Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: There's a for loop inside the goroutine, it runs as many times as needed until the queue is empty, more than 20 times, the concurrency is just limited to 20 concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed everyones suggestions and it seems to resolved my issue so I greatly appreciate it. I ended up removing the global WaitGroup like many suggested and had it passed in as a parameter(pointer) to clean up the code. As for the error issues before, it must have been maxing out the concurrent HTTP request like maxm had mentioned. Once I added a wait in between every 20 searches, I have not seen any errors.  The program runs a little slower than I would like but for learning purposes this has been helpful.

Below is the major change the code needed.

```
        counter := 0
    for key, _ := range locationMap {
        if(counter >= 20) {
            wg.Wait()
            counter = 0
        }
        wg.Add(1)
        frmtSearch := key + "search/sss?format=rss&query=" + strings.Replace(p.SearchRequest, " ", "%20", -1)
        go cityRoutine(queue, frmtSearch, &wg)
        counter++
    }
```